# Objectio dB database for Java desktop persistance

Tags: java, database, desktop-application, objectbox-java

I have been trying out object ox io for Java. It has been working well on Android hence I decided to go with it on Java desktop implementation.

The problem I am facing is that I can save my data at run time but when I restart the app or desktop app the data is gone, is forgotten, which is very strange. I have tried to look for an explanation but haven't found anything on this. Can anyone help or have an idea why this is? In the mean time I have reverted to using SQLite. The app is intended to be very big and have a lot of multi-threads.

here is a sample

```java
import io.objectbox.BoxStore;
import io.objectbox.DebugFlags;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DBObjectManager {

    public static DBObjectManager  objectIOAccessInstance ;
    private BoxStore store;


    private DBObjectManager() {
        File tempFile = null;
        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile("objectdb", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tempFile.delete();
         store = MyObjectBox.builder()
                .directory(tempFile)              
                .debugFlags(DebugFlags.LOG_QUERIES | DebugFlags.LOG_QUERY_PARAMETERS)
                .build();
    }

    public static DBObjectManager getinstance() {
        if (objectIOAccessInstance == null) {
            objectIOAccessInstance = new DBObjectManager();
        }
        return objectIOAccessInstance;
    }

    public BoxStore getStore() {
        return store;
    }
}
```

Comment: How shall anybody be able to help you if provide close to nothing of information? How do you configure, initialize, use the db? Maybe you are using an in-memory db. How shall we know?

Comment: i have edited the question with sample code @mipa .

Comment: hmm ... how is this related to javafx?

Comment: this is a class that i will use anywhere in any other java app , in this case, I am using this with JavaFX

Comment: using problematic code in _whatever_ context doesn't make it related to _whatever_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new temporary file each time when you execute your application. I guess that explains your problem.

From the docs:

> creates a new empty file in the specified directory. deleteOnExit()
> method is called to delete the file created by this method.

Comment: yes its working now, so the question is for me, does the app lose access to the files every time we run to make an in-memory type of database every time there is a run, since its temp files are written to disk?

Comment: Just use a non-temporary file.